# Moving SSD to another system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have a laptop that has two SSDs. One 128GB that has Windows 10, other one 512 has Linux(16.04) but there I made partition 120GB for Linux and other for either documents when using Windows (localDisk D) and documents for Linux. The thing is I already tried to just take SSD where Ubuntu is move to another system and tried with Live CD to install GRUB using boot-repair but unsuccessfully. Boot-repair gives error: "grub-efi-amd64-signed purge canceled". I tried to search on Internet but with every "solution" I didn't succeed. What is the best way to do this ? My goal is not to install development environment again but I want this SSD to be on new system because I bought new laptop with better specs.

Every help or insight is really appreciative..

Best regards

Comment: You need to learn about UEFI, first and foremost, because almost all machines from 10 years ago or newer have that instead of BIOS. Then you'll understand what you want to do isn't easy if that SSD doesn't contain the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Comment: I know about UEFI and Legacy BIOS, its not problem in that. Even you can run USB (Live CD) in Legacy or UEFI. The thing is when I installed on old laptop GRUB2 using boot-repair I have boot "stuff" on both drives (sda2 - Windows and sdb1 - Linux). Now what comes in my mind, is it a good approach to remove on old system grub and then move the disk and try again ?

Comment: No, you don't know about UEFI, not enough anyway. A live USB can boot both ways because it was made with support for both, for obvious reasons. Not an installed system! That system was installed in one way **or** the other and cannot be easily changed from one to the other. Again, you need an ESP for booting in UEFI mode and you don't have one in the SSD, reason why Boot Repair couldn't install Grub (in UEFI mode). Bottom line: It takes way less time to install it again than to make it boot in those conditions.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info but can you provide then answer ? Some guidnes or what I need to do for ESP?

Comment: I don't intend to answer something you can easily google about. My only comment is: *It takes way less time to install it again than to make it boot in those conditions.* Reason: You would need to resize and move partitions and that isn't risk free and that alone can take a lot of time to finish; then you'd need to reinstall Grub either with Boot Repair or manually from a live session. It's simply not worth the time and the risk of data loss.